# Show only min and max values on x-axis in column chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to format the x-axis of a column chart in Excel such that the x-axis displays ***only*** the min and max values? I will like to reduce the 'clutter' in the chart by eliminating intermediary values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to chart data on range A1:B10. The column A is the one used for the x-axis. If you don't want intermediate values, add a third column, say column C, and copy only the first and last value of A:

```
C1: =A1
C2 to C9: = ""
C10: =A10
```

Right click the chart and choose Select Data. In the x-axis label range, choose C1:10. Because you only have values on the first and last cell of column C, all intermediate values will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If your x-axis is a date axis (i.e. you have time series data), you can change the "units" for the axis to a longer period of time than the individual observations thusly:

1. Right-click to format the axis
2. Under "axis options" --> Units --> Major
3. Choose a number of units equal to your number of observations minus one.

That should give you a plot where the first and last time periods are labelled, and everything in between isn't.  For example, if you have one calendar year of monthly observations, and put 11 in the box, only "January" and "December" will appear as axis labels.

If your x-axis is a text axis (i.e. anything but dates), you can still fiddle with how labels appear, but it's in a different place:

1. Format axis
2. Labels --> Specify interval unit
3. Again, choose a number equal to the number of observations minus one.

For example, if your axis organized around the letters of the Roman alphabet, and you put 25 in the box, only "A" and "Z" will appear as axis labels.